# JSON.stringify not working - undefined

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I'm getting into troubles with JSON in javascript. I have one code where I use the JSON.stringify all the time and never had problems with it. But when I enter my application, I cannot use it. It keeps returning me in console (Google Chrome) the following:

**Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function lista.js:188**

which is definetly the line where the stringify function is on.

Do any of you know any ways to solve this problem? It's like the JSON unit is not found or something. Or maybe a workaround... I'll post my code below:

Thanks in advance!

in my index.php I have a header with:

```
<script src="http://ajax.cdnjs.com/ajax/libs/json2/20110223/json2.js"></script>
```

> //This is the code to the function.

```
function Salvar(AIdProcesso){
var Respostas = new Array ();
var Registro = 1;

$('.chkResposta').each(function(){
    var chk = $(this);

    var IdTitulo = chk.attr("idTitulo");
    var Valor    = chk.isChecked() ? 'true' : 'false';

    var Item = [IdTitulo, Valor];

    Respostas[Registro] = Item;
    Registro = Registro+1;
});

$('.edtValor').each(function(){
    var edt = $(this);

    var IdTitulo = edt.attr("idTitulo");
    var Valor    = edt.val();

    var Item = [IdTitulo, Valor];

    Respostas[Registro] = Item;
    Registro = Registro+1;
});

//this is where I get the error!!
var JsonString = JSON.stringify(Respostas, function(){}, 2);

$.post(        
    'processos/lista.php', {
        Op: 'Inscricao',
        Id: AIdProcesso,
        Itens: JsonString
    }, function(rHtml){
        JSON = jQuery.parseJSON(rHtml);

        $('.breadcrumb').html(JSON.breadcrumb);
        $('.Box').html(JSON.box);
});
}
```

Comment: Can you create a JSFiddle so we can test the code more easily? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

On this line

```
var JsonString = JSON.stringify(Respostas, function(){}, 2);
```

you're passing in a *replacer function* that doesn't return anything. The replacer function you pass into `stringify` is expected to return something. Refer to [the specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.12.3) for details.

---

Side note: You're including json2.js in your page, but note that [all modern browsers](http://caniuse.com/#search=json), as well as IE8, support JSON natively. Unless you need to support IE7 and earlier, or truly old browsers from other vendors, you don't need that script anymore.